# Having issue with May Month in Classic ASP using CDate

Tags: api, vbscript, asp-classic

We have created a date converter in April month, 
Which was working great until 30th April, But now it's not working.

Issue happen when month change to May, 
Here is my code with static data.

```
thisMonth = Month(CDate("April 29, 2017"))
```

This is working, But if I add month May,

```
thisMonth = Month(CDate("May 1, 2017"))
```

It's giving me following error,

> Microsoft VBScript runtime
>   error '800a000d'
>   Type mismatch: 'CDate'

This is really strange behaviour.

By the way, this is in the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely depends on what the [LCID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047(WinEmbedded.10).aspx) is set to as to whether VBScript will be able to cast the date correctly.

So, if you want to cast dates in the form `dd mmm, yyyy` you will need to make sure that you use [`Call SetLocale(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xf99h19.aspx) for `2057` or `1033` before calling `CDate()`.

Here is a basic example that re-creates the issue *(guessed that LCID: 1081 is what you are likely set to in Classic ASP, depending on the Server's system regional settings)*;

```vb
<%
Option Explicit

Const LOCALE_EN_GB = 2057
Const LOCALE_EN_US = 1033
Const LOCALE_HI = 1081

Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001

Call Response.Write("Current LCID: " & GetLocale() & "<br /><br />")
Call Response.Write("--- Starting Tests ---<br />")
Call TestDates(LOCALE_EN_GB)
Call TestDates(LOCALE_EN_US)
Call TestDates(LOCALE_HI)

Sub TestDates(loc)
  Call SetLocale(loc)
  Call Response.Write("LCID: " & loc & " Test Date: " & FormatDateTime(Date(), vbLongDate) & "<br />")

  Dim ds: ds = Array("April 29, 2017", "May 1, 2017")
  Dim d

  For Each d In ds
    Call Response.Write(CDate(d) & "<br />")
  Next
End Sub
%>
```

Output:

```
Current LCID: 2057

--- Starting Tests ---
LCID: 2057 Test Date: 03 May 2017
29/04/2017
01/05/2017
LCID: 1033 Test Date: Wednesday, May 3, 2017
4/29/2017
5/1/2017
LCID: 1081 Test Date: 03 मई 2017
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'CDate'
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [How To Use GetLocale() and SetLocale() in VBScript](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/232158/how-to-use-getlocale-and-setlocale-in-vbscript)
- [How to set the ASP Locale ID per the browser's language settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/229690/how-to-set-the-asp-locale-id-per-the-browser-s-language-settings)